# adding an image to telerik data grid column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I want to add an image to a data grid column, I am using telerik grid for this, however I get the following error, its on Line 51:

Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'

Source Error:

```
Line 49:     column.Bound(o => o.HoursWorked).Title("Hours");
Line 50:     column.Template(o =>
Line 51:     {%>
Line 52:     <img src="/Content/img/delete.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete"/>
Line 53:     <%
```

Here is how I am trying to add an image to the column:

```
<div>
<%=Html.CustomGridFor("Hours", "WorkHours", "HoursWorked", GridOptions.EnableSelecting, Model).Columns(column =>
   {
     column.Bound(o => o.DateWorked).Title("Date").Width("65px");
     column.Bound(o => o.Description).Title("Description").Width("120px");
     column.Bound(o => o.HoursWorked).Title("Hours");
     column.Template(o =>
     {%>
     <img src="/Content/img/delete.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete" onclick="javascript:deleteHours();" />
     <%
     }).Title("").ClientTemplate(
     "<img src=\"/Content/img/delete.png\" alt=\"Delete\" title=\"Delete\"/>"
     ).Width(15);
     }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 270px;" });
     %>
</div>
```

Tried this too:

```
<div>
<%=Html.CustomGridFor("Hours", "WorkHours", "HoursWorked", GridOptions.EnableSelecting, Model).Columns(column =>
   {
     column.Bound(o => o.DateWorked).Title("Date").Width("65px");
     column.Bound(o => o.Description).Title("Description").Width("120px");
     column.Bound(o => o.HoursWorked).Title("Hours");

        column.Template(o =>
        {
        %>
            <img 
                alt="Delete" 
                src="/Content/img/delete.png" 
              />
        <%
        });

</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a client and server template? I think this demo is almost exactly what you want, just use your delete image instead: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/templatesserverside

Comment: @Jisaak I tried the way suggested in demo you provided, still get the same error about invalid expression term ')'. I have updated my code above

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
<div>
<%=Html.CustomGridFor("Hours", "WorkHours", "HoursWorked", GridOptions.EnableSelecting, Model).Columns(column =>
        {
           column.Bound(o => o.DateWorked).Title("Date").Width("65px");
           column.Bound(o => o.Description).Title("Description").Width("120px");
           column.Bound(o => o.HoursWorked).Title("Hours");
           column.Template(o => string.Empty).Title("")
                 .ClientTemplate(
                      "<img src=\"/Content/img/delete.png\" alt=\"Delete\" title=\"Delete\"/>")
                 .Width(15);
        }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 270px;" });
%>
</div>
```

Comment: I was still getting the error: Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term ')' Removing ";" from the last line does add another column with no heading, but still dont see the delete image.

Comment: Could you show what is html in client that is generated in this column with no heading?

Comment: This is what I see:
<TD class=t-last></TD>

Comment: I got it to work this way: 

column.Template(o =>
            {
                %>
                <img src="/Content/img/delete.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete")" />
                <%
            }).Title("").ClientTemplate(
                      "<img src=\"/Content/img/delete.png\" alt=\"Delete\" title=\"Delete\"/>")
                 .Width(25).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" });
        }).Render();

And removing the "=" from first line